# How can I use a routed command on the view from a view model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to use a RoutedCommand on my view so that I can use the CanExecute functionality, but the only way I can get it to work is with a DelegateCommand from Prism. When I try to use the RoutedCommand the button stays inactive and the CanExecute function never gets used.

I've tried putting a CommandBinding on my XAML but that gives a "Only instance methods on the generated or code-behind class are valid." error. Here is that code:

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="AddCommand"
                Executed="my:SettingsDialogViewModel.AddCommandMethod"
                CanExecute="my:SettingsDialogViewModel.AddCommandMethodCanExecute" />
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

I've also tried setting up a CommandBinding in code, but that doesn't help either. I'm just not sure how to get it to work, short of sticking it in the code-behind, or implementing some ridiculously complicated looking thing I've found on the web.

Thanks for any help :)

EDIT:
Here are the methods I am trying to use:

```
public void AddCommandMethod()
{
    if (SelectedMain != null)
    {
        SelectedMain.IsDirty = true;
        _faveAppList.Add(SelectedMain);
        SelectedMain.ListOrder = _faveAppList.Count;
        _mainAppList.Remove(SelectedMain);
        _listDirty = true;
    }
}
public void AddCommandMethodCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.CanExecute = true;
}
```

Comment: Is that a static method?  If so, you'll need to use the `x:Static` syntax.

Comment: The only thing I can suggest with the code you've provided is to go over MVVM web sites again. You also might want to check out PRISM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't the proper MVVM notation. I'll provide one way of doing this.

```
// MyView.cs
public class MyView : UserControl
{ 
    public MyViewViewModel ViewModel 
    { 
        get { return (MyViewViewModel) DataContext;}
        set { DataContext = value; }
    }
}

// DelegateCommand.cs
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
      private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
      private readonly Action<object> _execute;

      public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute)
           : this(execute, null) {}

      public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
      {
           _execute = execute;
           _canExecute = canExecute;
      }

      public override bool CanExecute(object parameter)
      {
          if (_canExecute == null)
          {
            return true;
          }
          return _canExecute(parameter);
      }

      public override void Execute(object parameter)
      {
        _execute(parameter);
      }     
 }

 // MyViewViewModel.cs
 public class MyViewViewModel 
 {
    public ICommand AddCommand {get;set;}

    public MyViewViewModel()
    {
          AddCommand = new DelegateCommand (AddCommandMethod, AddCommandMethodCanExecute);
    }

    private void AddCommandMethod (object parameter)
    {

    }

    private bool AddCommandMethodCanExecute(object parameter)
    {
         // Logic here
         return true;
    }
 }

 // MyView.xaml

 <Button Command="{Binding AddCommand}" />
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize I could use the DelegateCommand in Prism with a CanExecute function. Chalk it up to a 'DOH!' moment on my part.

Answer (score 1):

A better option would be to implement the [`ICommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.aspx) interface and write your logic in the implemented methods.  Then your view model can return your custom command and you could just bind to it from your view.

This will separate the actual command implementation from your view model but you can still nicely implement the logic within your view model.

Something like this:

```
public abstract class BaseCommand : ICommand
{
    // needed to connect to WPF's commanding system
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public abstract bool CanExecute(object parameter);
    public abstract void Execute(object parameter);
}

public class AddCommand : BaseCommand
{
    private readonly MyViewModel _vm;
    public AddCommand(MyViewModel vm)
    {
        this._vm = vm;
    }
    public override bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        // delegate back to your view model
        return _vm.CanExecuteAddCommand(parameter);
    }
    public override void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _vm.ExecuteAddCommand(parameter);
    }
}

public class MyViewModel
{
    public ICommand AddCommand { get; private set; }
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        AddCommand = new AddCommand(this);
    }

    public bool CanExecuteAddCommand(object parameter)
    {
    }

    public void ExecuteAddCommand(object parameter)
    {
    }
}
```

Then just bind controls that issues the command.

```
<Button Command="{Binding AddCommand}">...</Button>
```